# Post probability after some event occurs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In a shop total of 40 customers come every month with a standard deviation 1.
In the first 15 days of month only 5 customers came.
What is the expected customer for this 15 days period?

edit:  Customer number per month is gaussian random variable.
Thank you  @obscurans

Comment: Welcome to math.SE.  what are your thoughts? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I think it is 35, but somehow I could not place the numbers in Bayes rule.

Comment: This question is wildly underdefined. You have nowhere near enough information to get an answer.

Comment: @obscurans what should be defined to answer this question?

Comment: A ton of things: you have several distributions with missing info. (1) per month - all you know is mean/stdev (2) first 15 days of the month (3) *conditional on 5 coming in the first 15 days*, what happens to the next 15 day period. Nothing stops the following wildly different situations: (a) because there's only 5 customers, there's going to be 40 coming next (because otherwise, you'd have 35 in the first 15 days and none the rest of the month), vs (b) flip these situations, with slightly changed numbers to fit "40 average/1 stdev".

Comment: @obscurans thanks for the information, I should add the distrubituon type which is normally distrubuted (Gaussian)   But I don't get why other situations are important

Comment: Do the customers come with any money, or just with a standard deviation $1$? Does the merchant accept standard deviations as payment for his/her goods?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the expected customer for this 15 days period?

In my opinion it's 35.

Here is my explanation:

$X\sim N[40;1^2]$

$$f_{X|X>5}(x)=\frac{1}{1-F_X(5)}f_X(x)=1.12\cdot 10^{-268}f_X(x)=f_X(x)$$

Thus the conditional expected number of customer in the month is always

$$\mathbb{E}[X|X>5]=40$$

that is 35 remaining in the rest of the month